# While using min-inline-size,is it possible to give direction from right to left in css

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to give background color to the icon present in the right hand side of the page. But background color is applied only for the image as a block. But actually what I need is background should start from the right side of the page and should end at the left side of the page. So I set the min-inline-size as 100%. This resolved the background issue. Now the image is in the left hand side. But I'm not getting how to achieve this?

```
<img src="excelpng.jpg" style="height: 25px; overflow: hidden; background-color: darkred; display: inline-block; min-inline-size: 100%" alt="">
```

Comment: please provide proper code/example to explain

Comment: `<img src="excelpng.jpg" style="height:25px;overflow: hidden;background-color: darkred;display: inline-block;min-inline-size: 100%;"/>
`

Comment: Hi vaishalikapadia ,Thank you for your time. I have attached a sample code.

Comment: Please add this information to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `width: 100%; text-align: right;` to `img`

```css
img {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 1px;
  right: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  min-inline-size: 100%;
  height:25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: darkred;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;    
}
```

```html
<img src="excelpng.jpg">
```

Hope this helps:)